# Replace an existing subnet on azure databricks with a new bigger subnet

Tags: azure-databricks

We have a new databricks instance on Azure and looks like capacity will not be enough. So my question is if we create a new subnet with larger capacity can we just replace the existing subnet on the current instance of databricks with a new subnet? And if we can replace the existing subnet, then how can we go about it?

Or is it possible to add an additional subnet to azure databricks instance?

Comment: Why a vote to close the question?

Comment: This question has closed due to does not meet SO guidelines. Please do ask your question on [Microsoft Q&A platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html) using [azure-databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/topics/azure-databricks.html) tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible right now.  The solution would be to create new workspace and migrate everything into it.  The Databricks Labs project has two projects: [migrate](https://github.com/databrickslabs/migrate) and [databricks-sync](https://github.com/databrickslabs/databricks-sync) that could be used for migration between workspaces.

Update, October 2023: `databricks-sync` isn't maintained anymore, and `migrate` has the coverage for a limited set of resources. Current recommendation is to use [Databricks Terraform Exporter](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/guides/experimental-exporter) that supports broader set of resources. Although it doesn't support Hive Metastore export - the corresponding functionality could be used from the `migrate` tool.